# how to enable libx264 for ffmpeg on macos

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running a code that runs ffmpeg and breaks down because of libx264 with the following error:

Unknown encoder 'libx264'

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py", line 661, in _append_data
    self._proc.stdin.write(im.tostring())
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

So I upgrade ffmpeg to the latest and see that libx264 is installed as shown: Using Brew on MacOs

```
==> Pouring x264-r3027_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz

 /usr/local/Cellar/x264/r3027_1: 11 files, 5.5MB
```

But when I do

```
ffmpeg encoders | grep 264
```

I get --disable-libx264 on the last line:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
  configuration: --prefix=/anaconda3 --cc=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --disable-doc --enable-shared --enable-static
```

--enable-zlib --enable-pic --enable-gpl
--enable-version3 --disable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-openssl --disable-gnutls --enable-libvpx --enable-pthreads --enable-libopus --enable-postproc **--disable-libx264**

Seems like I have to change --disable-libx264 to --enable-libx264 but not sure where and how it is done. Could not find it under /anaconda3 since: --prefix=/anaconda3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed Brew and instead ran conda install ffmpeg and it is enabled there.

Answer (score 1):

If you install x264 and ffmpeg using Conda, you need today (might change in the future) to specify the versions to install. For instance, this combination works fine for me:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge x264=='1!161.3030' ffmpeg=4.3.2
```

If I now run the command `ffmpeg`, I can see that I have the flag `--enable-libx264`. The full output is:

```
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with clang version 11.1.0
  configuration: --prefix=/Users/vincent/opt/anaconda3/envs/test2 --cc=x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --disable-doc --disable-openssl --enable-avresample --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libx264 --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-version3 --enable-zlib --enable-libmp3lame --pkg-config=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1627813741069/_build_env/bin/pkg-config
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

I guess the problem comes from the version of ffmpeg installed by default today (when this post was written). Indeed, if in a newly created virtual environment I install x264 and ffmpeg without specifying the versions to use, I get x264 `1!161.3030` and ffmpeg `4.0`. Using a newer version of ffmpeg seems to solve the problem.

The idea is to use compatible package versions. To create the installation line I propose above, I simply specified the latest versions available on conda-forge of both x264 and ffmpeg package. To get the list of available Conda packages for x264 and ffmpeg, simply use:

```
conda search -c conda-forge -f x264
conda search -c conda-forge -f ffmpeg
```